# is that possible to set ImageSource as null in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, imagesource

Does anyone knows how to set ImageSource to null in xaml.
Something like this

```
<ImageSource x:Key="tt">null</ImageSource>
```

thanks!

Comment: It doesn’t work like that, by declaring the <ImageSource>-Tag you already call the constructor. You can try something like that: <x:Null x:Key="tt" />. I assume it probably won't work either, because the system probably can't differentiate between a missing key or null. Because, at least TryFindResource() returns null, if the key is missing.

Comment: Another thought, I just assumed that you want do define a Resource with Key "ll" that should be an ImageSource of value null. But maybe you can explain what you want to do, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Here is the case,I use ImageSource as DynamicResource ,There are many ImageSource in Resources.I use ImageBrush too.ImageBrush's property ImageSource referenced to ImageSource one to one.   So ,when i change the ImageSource ,The ImageBrush get update.The problem is not all of ImageSource should have value.in some cases,ImageSource should be null.any advices?

Comment: How about not defining the Resource at all. If I remember correctly a missing Resource should not be a problem for "DynamicResource". (As opposite to StaticResource, which throws an Exception if the ResourceKey is missing.) – In fact, I just tried it. It works, DynamicResource to missing Key is valid. StaticResource would throw exception. using <x:Null x:Key="…"/> works also. All of these solution show blue squiggly line under code, because it is a XAML error in XAML editor (but not at runtime).

Comment: Also <x:Null x:Key="…"/> must not be the first element under <Resources>, otherwise XAML would set Resources to null and throws an error for every additional element. Unless you explicitly define a <ResourceDictionary> inside <Resources>.

Comment: Set ImageSource to a full transprent image may be the only way to get this effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a property to `null` in XAML like this:

```
Source="{x:Null}"
```

You can't create an instance of an `ImageSource` since it's an abstract class.

You could define a `BitmapImage` but then you to set either the `UriSource` or `StreamSource` property somehow.

Comment: Use empty BitmapImage gets this error"Property 'UriSource' or property 'StreamSource' must be set"

Comment: @pivnothebearrrrrrrrr: Right. Simply set the property to `{x:Null}` or don't set it at all then. It makes much sense to define a resource that doesn't return anything.

Comment: @pivnothebearrrrrrrrr: Does this answer your question or what is your current issue?

Answer (score 1):

In XAML, that would be `{x:Null}` (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/xnull-markup-extension))

You might have to use it a bit differently than in your example :

```
<YourControl x:Key="tt" Content="{x:Null}"></ImageSource>
```

Or use the actual property that you want to set to null instead of `Content`.

If you have an ImageSource property of your YourControl, that should be something like :

```
<YourControl ImageSource="{x:Null}">
```